# Prevent "widows" - items alone in a row - when using css grid

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I created a responsive grid which should contain rows of 4, 3, 2 or 1 items, depending on the window size. Hard requirement from *Design* is that no *widows* and no half filled rows are allowed. So for 11 items, there could be two rows of four items and one of three, or three rows of three items and one of two items, or... . You get the idea.

To solve the problem, I created a *css grid*:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(264px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 24px;
```

This works fine for the resizing, but it does not take care of the widow problem. At first I did the naive approach of selecting the last item with a `last-of-type` selector and giving it a `grid-row: 1 / -1` style, but that does not ensure that the row above is fully filled.

I guess there won't be a css only solution. Is there a way for an element to realize that it is alone in a row, or that it has to grow to fill the row? I had an idea using the `nextSibling` property to select the last child via *JavaScript* and maybe determine via the page offset if it fills the whole row. But my problem is that I can't hardcode the width of the screen.

Alternatively, is there a way to tell an element to spread until the end of the row? I tried this, but it did not work:

```
.card:last-of-type {
  grid-column-end: span -1;
}
```

[Click here](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/eYZOBYG) for minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What defines a "half filled row"? Is that just "No rows of 2 where there are also rows of 4"? (I can't think of any other ways you would get a half row without it also being a widow with the other conditions you have included)

Comment: Sorry, seems like I was not precise enough. Basically I mean there should be no empty space. So if there are two elements in a row, then they should grow to fill up the empty space completely. It is ok to mix the amount of items in a row. So four items, four items and two items would be okay for a total of ten items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) instead of [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid). This way it can stretch with the screen size.
We use `25%` for a 4 column layout. Subtracting `1rem` for a bit of margin. (0.5 left + 0.5 right)

*(Open snippet in fullscreen to see it working)*

```css
.my-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  min-width: 264px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #00000026;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: .5rem;
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">blub</div>
</div>
```